# How to display backward referenced model instances in Django admin interface?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I've ManyToMany references between 2 models, comparable to [Django's Many-To-Many example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/):

```py
# models.py

from django.db import models

class Publication(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['title']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Article(models.Model):
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    publications = models.ManyToManyField(Publication)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['headline']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.headline
```

```py
# admin.py
from .models import Article, Publication

admin.site.register(Article)
admin.site.register(Publication)
```

In the default Django admin interface I see for every article which publications it is linked to. But I don't see for a single publication which article it is linked to. How can I add this information to the admin interface?

Comment: Can you include your admin.py code?

Comment: It's the simplest one you can think of. I added it to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Django allows you to look up M2M relationships in reverse by using the `modelname_set` attribute on each object. You can use this by defining a callable in `admin.py`, and including it in list_display like so:

**admin.py**

```py
@admin.register(Publication)
class PublicationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['title', 'articles']

    def articles(self, object):
        return ", ".join([str(a) for a in object.article_set.all()])

admin.site.register(Article)
```

You can modify how `articles` is displayed, of course. This is a simple example. Note this could get unwieldy if your publication has lots of articles.